# How do I list required gems for my system, so they are installed automatically when deploying it?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby but I really enjoyed it.
I used Aptana Studio 3 as an IDE, but I feel it lacks support (even though I installed the undle). When I created a Ruby project, there were no files inside it.
I added a test.rb file and started playing with it.

Now I hav a simple project in which I needed to install some gems. To do so I opened the CMD, navigated to my project's folder and issued the command "gem install xxxx". On my test.rb I include the gems using require 'xxxx'.

What is the best practice to add gems?
If I ever wanted to deploy this application, I would need to add the gems to my production server. Is there any way I can list the required gems so that the server intalls it automatically when I run deploy the application?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a Gemfile, it is used to manage the gem required by an application.
http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on where you are deploying to but I like to use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) for deployment. Capistrano will install the gems for you by running bundler which reads your Gemfile.

Also checkout [bundler](http://bundler.io/).  It will read your Gemfile (create one if you don't have one). To install your gems it is as simple as:

```
$ bundle install
```